# UIToolbar being transparent instead of translucent.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uitoolbar

I'm simply adding a `UIToolbar` above a `UITableView`.

By default, the appearance of the toolbar should be a whitish translucent color however (like the navigation bar right?).

I am getting an almost fully transparent color (I can totally see through the toolbar into the `UITableViewCell` contents very clearly).

Does anybody else have this problem?

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check these following helping links upon the `Bar color for iOS 7 (UIToolbar and UINavigationBar)`:

1) http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/bar-color-calculator-for-ios7/

2) http://www.objc.io/issue-5/iOS7-hidden-gems-and-workarounds.html

And also I suggest you to read the Apple Documentation for [UIToolbar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I'm not having problems with the toolbar color nor am I having problems making the toolbar translucent or non translucent. The translucent property is set to YES by default. The issue here is that the translucency is too much that the view becomes almost transparent. Setting the barTintColor to another color just gives a hint of that color at the top of the toolbar as seen in the screenshot above where there's a tad bit of white tint. Could this be a bug? Thanks.

Comment: then you can manually set the toolbar color of your desire and your problem will solve?

Comment: Nope. Setting any tint color did not matter. I will still get an overly transparent toolbar as seen in the screenshot above. Shouldn't the translucency be like those in UINavigationBar or "Control Center" background?

Comment: I guess this the bug in ios7, I suggest you to put your toolbar in uiview view and then add in your table you will achieve your required functionality in this way hopelfully.